# How to Add SignalR to Worker Service in .net Core 3.0

Tags: .net, .net-core, apache-kafka, signalr

I am working on a worker service that consumes a Kafka Message.
I want to make a signalR event when I message is retrieved, but cant make it work currently.

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
      {
          services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
          services.AddTransient<IKafkaClient, KafkaClient>();
          services.AddSignalR();
      })
      .Build())
        {
            // Start the host
            await host.StartAsync();

            // Wait for the host to shutdown
            await host.WaitForShutdownAsync();
        }
}
```

and in my worker service

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly IKafkaClient _kafkaClient;
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _notificationHub;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger,
                  IKafkaClient kafkaClient,
                  IHubContext<NotificationHub> notificationHub)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _kafkaClient = kafkaClient;
        _notificationHub = notificationHub;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
      // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Comment: I cant add signalr to a worker service.

Comment: Yes its using dotnet core and worker service

Comment: Then you can try inject the service using dependency injection. Add the hub as singleton and inject it in your worker by getting the required service.

Comment: sorry, but what would be the address to listen for?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solve my problem by adding Task.Yield() in my ExecuteAsync method in my backgroundservice.

Answer (score 0):

On your startup `AddAdditionalServices` method add:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<NotificationHub>()
```

then inject it in your worker class like:

```cs
private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

private NotificationHub NotificationHub
{
    get
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<NotificationsHub>();
    }
}
```

you need create hub methods to be called from the class like:

```cs
public async Task BroadcastMessage(string message){
  // your code here
}
```

so you can call it in the worker.

```cs
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  // code here

 string message = // serialize kafka message

 await NotificationHub.BroadcastMessage(message)
}
```